# Java Scanner isn't reading my txt file

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner

I am a tad frustrated because something this simple is giving me problems. It's been a while since I fired up some Java but I'm pretty sure I've done everything right. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner("numbers.txt");
        while(input.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(input.nextInt());
        }

    }
}
```

I tried moving the file to the src folder. I also tried pointing the Scanner to a file `C://sample.txt` but that didn't work either.

I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: can you post up your stack trace please? what specific error compiler gives u?

Comment: I know it's just style but your class names should have an uppercase first letter. 'Driver' not 'driver.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) constructor points the `Scanner` at the contents of that string -- the string doesn't represent a filename. You can use `new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"))`.

Comment: If I wanted to point to a file in my C drive, is new Scanner(new File("C://numbers.txt")) supposed to work?

Comment: @HandleThatError Probably need C:\\ (the path has one backslash, but you need to put two in the string for Java to interpret it correctly) instead of C://

Comment: It says that the file does not exist.

Comment: @HandleThatError

It is possible that it is a permissions issue - try giving it a path that isn't at the root of C, e.g., C:\myfolder\myfile.txt